# how to rewrite .every() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JS and trying to rewrite .every in javascript to understand how it works. My understanding is it should take in any parameter and if it passes, it returns true. My thought was thinking of a class of students grades on a test and using every.

Example 1: Did "every" student get above a 90?

Example 2: Did "every" student get above a 30?

I have a feeling my code isn't written properly to take in these two checks to make them always work.

```
var arr = [62, 45, 88, 89, 36];

var every = function (collection, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (collection[i] < value) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

every(arr, 90)
```

Comment: Looks like it should work just fine, but what's wrong with the native Array.every, or at least polyfilling it ?

Comment: Looks like it will work correctly. Did you try it?

Comment: Why do you think your code is incorrect?  What did it return when you tried it?

Comment: looks good to me: http://jsfiddle.net/6Un2S/

Comment: @adeneo, im new to JS and was asked to rewrite .every to make sure I understood how it works.

Comment: @blurfus, am I understanding `.every` correctly, by example if I do `every(arr,90)`, it does return false. In English its 'true' that all the scores are less than 90, although it returns `false` which makes it seem that its not working right. Even though by definition here it should return `false`

Comment: @jstone: `Did "every" student get above a 90?`  No, they did not.  Therefore, `false`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, thanks for that :) so here is a scenario, if the array I sent in should check if every string begins with 'a'. I can write that in my every func pretty easily, although then every wouldn't work for this numbers example we have been discussing. So my question is, should every be used that way or should it do something generic and then accept any use case? That's where I got hung up, expecting it to accept all sorts of parameters and .every is just a generic function.

Comment: @jstone the issues seems to be that the name of the function `every` is not clear on what it is asking.  The function should be renamed `isEveryGradeHigherThan()` or something of the sort.  Then, as @RocketHazmat states, the answer is more clear (true or false) because the question is more specific.

Comment: @jstone as to your second question, you can create a separate function to handle `strings` along with a name for the function that describes what the function does.  For example, `doesEveryItemInArrayStartWithLetter( arrOfItems, letterToCheck)`

Answer (score 0):

every takes two arguments, the function that is applied to each array element until one returns false, and the object scope, if any.

The test function automatically passes each element the item, its index and a reference to the Array.

If every item passes the function test, boolean true is returned, otherwise false.

```
Array.prototype.every=Array.prototype.every || function(fun, scope){
        var T= this, len= T.length;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            for(var i= 0; i<len; i++){
                if(i in T){
                    if(fun.call(scope, T[i], i, T)== false) return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```